# PHP to download and Return Raw JSON Data?

Tags: php, json

I've been working on an tool that displays information from an API using PHP. Up until now I've been trying to echo individual fields of information one at a time in order to format them. Now I'm curious is it possible for me to somehow return just the whole unparsed JSON return, by this I mean just the raw JSON as it it. Can I somehow call that into a PHP page?

Here's an example of the JSON I'm referring to..

https://api.data.gov/sam/v4/registrations/7800853870000?return_values=full&api_key=CCHRrZMMc1s9I1dxtk4bwTPdoT4A1Xjck9w4Lii0

Comment: `json_decode` and `json_encode`?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you want, but this will show " just the raw JSON as it is" : `print_r($json)`.  Wrap it in `<pre>` markup tags to make it look nicer..

Comment: Please post a sample of what you want to encode in json.

Comment: I don'r want to encode the JSON I want to just load the raw untouched JSON into a PHP page. Just have it appear completely unformatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to output the `json` from [https://api.data.gov/sam/v4/registrations/...](https://api.data.gov/sam/v4/registrations/7800853870000?return_values=full&api_key=CCHRrZMMc1s9I1dxtk4bwTPdoT4A1Xjck9w4Lii0) on your website, you can use:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$url = "https:///someJsonUrl";
echo file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: `echo file_get_contents($url);` is sufficient to display the raw JSON on any page,  with or without another content, and that `header()` is useful when you display only the JSON file (the browser will format the JSON).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Client URL Library` for this.

Here's the reference:

- [Client URL Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$searchURI = 'http://api.data.gov/sam/v4/registrations/7800853870000?return_values=full&api_key=CCHRrZMMc1s9I1dxtk4bwTPdoT4A1Xjck9w4Lii0';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $searchURI);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$jsonData=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// $jsonData is your row json data
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $jsonData;
```